# Difference between interlocked variable access (on boolean) and std::atomic_flag

Tags: c++, winapi, atomic, interlocked

I was wondering what the differences are between accessing a boolean value using Windows' `interlockedXXX` functions and using `std::atomic_flag`.

To my knowledge, both of them are lock-less and you can't set or read an `atomic_flag` directly. I wonder whether there are more differences.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/s8Qn4I

Comment: No differences, it just took a very long time to get std::atomic added to the standard.  The Interlocked functions existed 5 years before the 1st C++ standard was published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::atomic_flag` serves basically as a primitive for building other synchronization primitives. In case one needs to *set or read*,  it might make more sense to compare with `std::atomic<bool>`.

However, there are some additional (conceptual) differences:

- With `interlockedXXX`, you won't get portable code.
- `interlockedXXX` is a **function**, while `std::atomic_flag` (as well as `std::atomic`) is a **type**. That's a significant difference, since, you can use `interlockedXXX` with any suitable memory location, such as an element of `std::vector`. On the contrary, you cannot make a vector of C++ atomic flags or atomic bools, since the corresponding types do not meet the vector value type requirements. <sup>1</sup>

You can see the latter difference in the code created by @RmMm, where `flag` is an ordinary variable. I also added a case with `atomic<bool>` and you may notice that all the three variants produce the very same assembly:

https://godbolt.org/z/9xwRV6

---

<sup>[1] This problem should be addressed by [`std::atomic_ref`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0019r8.html) in C++20.</sup>